# Make repeater row checkable

Tags: c#, repeater

I have a ASP.NET repeater consists of image and label(wrap inside a div).
I want to make the repeater row work like a checkbox.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <div class="divItem">                                                              
           <asp:HiddenField ID="hfIID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
           <asp:Image ID="imgItem" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageURL") %>' />
           <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ItemName") %>'></asp:Label>
       </div>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

For example, the repeater have 10 items.

When a user select item 3 and item 5(similar like a checkbox) and press Save, I need to get the selected Item ID.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to add some client side scripting with jquery.

Here's how to do it:

in your .aspx define repeater as :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="divItem" id='divItem<%# Eval("ID") %>'>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfSelected" runat="server" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfIID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
            <asp:Image ID="imgItem" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageURL") %>' />
            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ItemName") %>'></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and then add this javascript:

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        $('.divItem').click(function () {

            var item = $(this);

            item.toggleClass("divItemSelected"); //mark div as selected: set background color, etc...

            var selector = "#" + item.attr("id") + " input[type='hidden'][id*='hfSelected']";

            var selected = $(selector).val();

            if (selected == "true") {
                $(selector).val("false");
            } else {
                $(selector).val("true");
            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

And then in code-behind on button click, you do this:

```
protected void OnSaveClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in rpt.Items)
    {
        HiddenField hfSelected = item.FindControl("hfSelected") as HiddenField;

        bool selected = false;

        bool.TryParse(hfSelected.Value, out selected);

        if (selected)
        {
            HiddenField hfIID = e.Item.FindControl("hfIID") as HiddenField;

            int id = Convert.ToInt32(hfIID.Value);
            // do appropriate action as needed.
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Regards,
Uros